# Magento 2: searchbox align using CSS

Tags: magento2

[image]

How can i move search box to center with the minicart. 
Please assist

Comment: Try moving through css. Create a parent block for both search and minicart and move that to center.

Comment: plz describe step by step........

Answer (score 0):

style-l.css file: add below code additionally

```
.header.content{
    max-width: 580px !important;
}

#search{
  width: 100% !important;
}

.block-search{
  margin-top: 15px !important;
}

.minicart-wrapper{
  margin-top: 1px !important;
}
```